# Why I failed to get the correct linux kernel version

Tags: kernel, source

I want to build a ubuntu kernel with debuginfo,so I did thease as following:

1. uname -a
   4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. Downloading the kernel source
   apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
3. Apply patches
   dpkg-source -x *.dsc
4. cd linux-hwe-4.13.0 && make kernelversion

   4.13.16

It doesn't match the running kernel, what's wrong with my steps?

Comment: May be due to the fact your kernel version is 4.13.0-43 and you are trying with 4.13.16.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode  
I dit as the url told me, but why the version is wrong...

Comment: See where the version problem stands : `cd linux-hwe-4.13.0 && make kernelversion 4.13.16`

Comment: Did you follow this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel instructions? btw: you can set several debug info by setting kernel parameters in  grub.